# is treemap in Java the same treemap in Information Visualization?

Tags: java, treemap, information-visualization

I was reading an article about `information visualization` and I came across one of its many representation methods, `treemap`. So I become wonder that is it the same treemap that is in Java or is it just a coincidence? And yea, I never used either of these treemap in real, so it was hard for me to recognize them from each other.

Comment: Did you check their documentation?  it is hard to know without more details

Comment: @ochi this is definition for treemap in information visualization : `In information visualization and computing, treemapping is a method for displaying hierarchical data by using nested rectangles.` and this is the treemap in Java : `A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap` `implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of`` its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time,` `depending on which constructor is used.'

Comment: No, they aren't in the same ballpark, not in the same league, and not the same sport ©. One looks like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping), while the other one looks like... Wait, the other one has no specific visual representation at all! Can you use a `TreeMap<K,V>` to represent a visual tree map? Maybe. But they are pretty unrelated.

Comment: Well, they are not related, one refers to a technique to visualize data, the other is a programming language construct (object) but it has nothing to do with graphics (at most, it will help with holding the data structure and/or values)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but like binary tree, i thought this treemap has both representation and implemented classes. do you know what i mean?

Comment: @ochi but like binary tree, i thought this treemap has both representation and implemented classes. do you know what i mean?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not related. Both of them use trees. Both of them use maps (but not even the same meaning of map).

A table you keep processed cannabis on could be called a "hash table". A treemap visualization is no more related to a `TreeMap` than a cannabis table is related to a `Hashtable`.

Comment: Haha. Urban dictionary defines Hash table as a piece of furniture composed entirely of cannabis. You're definition is more practical. People ought to adopt it!

Comment: maybe i need to explain why i thought they may be a like. just like binary trees in data structure, you can both make a demonstration on it and make an implementation of it. so i thought the treemap in info visu is a demo of the treemap in java since `public class TreeMap<K,V>`
`extends AbstractMap<K,V>`
i`mplements NavigableMap<K,V>`, ``Cloneable` `,` `Serializable`

Comment: @Ionesome I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Yes, you can visualize a `TreeMap`'s internal structure (just like you can visualize any data structure), but not using a treemap visualization.

Comment: so i thought since treemap's aim is to `In information visualization and computing, treemapping is a method for displaying hierarchical data by using nested rectangles.` so i thought they may share a common ground